# SQL query to removing rows when only one column value is duplicate

Tags: sql, sql-server

I am using sql server 2000
I have a table like below :

```
lr_no   seq len       
8402606 003 48
8410184 002 50
8410184 003 30
8411592 002 33
8415732 005 12
8416530 002 24
8415732 004 27
```

where 8410184    & 841573 are duplicated .

i want to filter the table such that if in case of duplicate lr_no's then row is selected depending on max(len) .

final output should be

```
    lr_no   seq len       
    8402606 003 48
    8410184 002 50
    8411592 002 33
    8416530 002 24
    8415732 004 27
```

can anyone help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT t.lr_no, t.seq, t.len
    FROM YourTable t
        INNER JOIN (SELECT lr_no, MAX(len) AS MaxLen
                        FROM YourTable
                        GROUP BY lr_no) q
            ON t.lr_no = q.lr_no
                AND t.len = q.MaxLen
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT 
 lr_no,   max(seq) as seq, max(len) as len
FROM
 table
GROUP BY 
 lr_no
```

*edit*

Okay, starting over:

```
SELECT 
  lr_no,   seq, len
FROM
 table t1
WHERE 
 not exists (
  SELECT 
   1 
  FROM 
   table t2 
  WHERE 
   t1.lr_no = t2.lr_no and 
   t2.len < t1.len)
```

Comment: this wont work since seq_no is diff in both cases . i want to neglect seq no and filter

Comment: no jus seethe output in case of 8415732 005 12 & 8415732 004 27 i want 8415732 004 27 to be slected since its length is greater but its seq_no is lesser .

Comment: The two max values are computed independently. You'd return `8410184 003 50` instead of `8410184 002 50`.

Comment: Okay, I've revised once again.